# UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(ScreeName.this) not working properly

Tags: blackberry, scroll, vertical-scrolling, fieldmanager

My screen have a lots of content so main `VerticalFieldManager` have `Scroll` property set to view all content using scroll.

All Content set properly and i can see all content using `Scrollview` But when i Scroll this page vertically than i click on my `Back Button` and i want to pop this screen .. when i click on back button first time nothing happened and when i click on second time this screen pop properly .  i dont know what happen at first click evnet .

Other screen pop properly which have not scroll on this screen .

check click evnet of Back Button

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(CurrenScreenName.this);
```

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: paste the code.. which will help to understand the problem in code.

Comment: please check my back button click event code

Comment: If you want to pop the current screen any where in the application...  write like this    UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen());

Comment: this problem occure in only in my BB storm 2 9550 . in other Simulator it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(UiApplication.getUiApplication().getA‌​ctiveScreen());
```

or

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Application.getApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {

 public void run() {
 UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen());                                                     
                   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happend to me, I used this:

```
do{
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen());
} while (UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen().toString().indexOf("YOUR_CLASS_NAME") < 0);
```